# Operator AND for multiple elements

Tags: symbols, math-operators, logic

I have an `AND` or `OR` logic operation. The operation takes as input multiple elements as follows:

```
 f(x) = (x_1 AND x_2 AND ,..., AND x_n)
```

Is there a shortened notation for this case, like sum of multiple elements (∑)?

Comment: There's `\land` ("logical and") and `\lor` ("logical or"). Both macros must occur in math mode. `\land` and `\lor` are synonyms for `\wedge` and `\vee`, respectively.

Comment: You can use `\bigwedge_{i=1}^{n}x_i` and `\bigvee_{i=1}^{n}x_i` for AND and OR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you may be looking for `\bigwedge` for collective-and and `\bigvee` for collective-or. (The ordinary-size symbol names, `\wedge` and `\vee`, are synonyms for `\land` and `\lor`, respectively: "logical and" and "logical or".)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
x_1\wedge x_2 \qquad y_1\vee y_2 \qquad
\bigwedge_{i=1}^n x_i \qquad \bigvee_{j=1}^m y_i
\]
\end{document}
```